# Laravel use query result in controller function

Tags: php, laravel-5

here is a part of the function in my controller

```
    $res= Commande::where('idClient',$id)->where('created_at',$datejour)->where('adresse',$addr)->get();
    if($res->isEmpty())
    {...
    }
    else
    {
        try {
        $resultat =\DB::table('ligne_commandes')->insert(['idCom'=>$res->idCom,'nomChaussure'=>$nomChaussure,'marque'=>$marque,'couleur'=>$couleur,'quantite'=>'1','pointure'=>$point]);
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Vous serez livrée dans un délai de 48 heures');
        }

        catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        return redirect()->back();

        }
    }

}
```

when i try to use $res->idCom, i got this error
Property [idCom] does not exist on this collection instance.
can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `get()` not `first()` to get result set.

Difference between both is that `get()` will return all the records(array) which matches the query criteria whereas `first()` will only return one record which matches the query criteria. So as per your query, I guess you are only expecting to get one result only. So use `first()` instead of `get()` like:

```
$res= Commande::where('idClient',$id)->where('created_at',$datejour)->where('adresse',$addr)->first();
```

Comment: @F Sorgho, please accept the answer if it solved your query